# add javascript get function to a href

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am very new to this

I have this link:

```
<a onclick = sendRequest('GET','room_chart.jsp') href=#>Show Chart</a>
```

but I need to generate dynamic address inside that link.

I created javascript:

```
    <script language="javascript">
        var selectedOption;
        var ROOM;
        var BUILDING;

        function GetLink(){
            selectedOption = document.getElementById("roomandbuildingid").options[e.selectedIndex].text;  //getting selected option
            ROOM = selectedOption.split("|")[0].trim().split(":")[1].trim(); //parsing text
            BUILDING = selectedOption.split("|")[1].trim().split(":")[1].trim(); //parsing text
            return "'room_chart.jsp?room="+ROOM+"&building="+ BUILDING+"'"; //returning url
        }
    </script>
```

but when I paste the function into it- it does not work!

```
<a onclick = sendRequest('GET',GetLink()) href=#>Show Chart</a>
```

Now, after debug, I found out that actually it creates the proper srting, but somehow my function is not willing to accept it as URL! It is quite a paradox- it creates correct string- if I hardcode it into the code- it works! But dynamic links from variables - don't work!

please help!

see below:
my js file:

```
function createRequestObject(){
    var req;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        //For IE 5+
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else{
        //Error for an old browser
        alert('Your browser is not IE 5 or higher, or Firefox or Safari or Opera');
    }
    return req;
}

//Make the XMLHttpRequest Object
var http = createRequestObject();

function sendRequest(method, url){
    if(method == "get" || method == "GET"){
        http.open(method,url);
        http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
        http.send(null);
       // alert( document.URL );
       // document.write (GetLink());
    }
}
function handleResponse(){
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        var response = http.responseText;
        if(response){  
            document.getElementById("ajax_res").innerHTML = response;
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: You need quotes inside that anchor tag.

Comment: This HTML and JavaScript are in a dreadfully outdated style. Whatever tutorial/learning resource you're using, I recommend abandoning posthaste.

Comment: I added more details- seems like it is working, but funtion is not 100% behaving.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL You should also add some references for the benefit of the noobs :)

Comment: @Andrew please be specific about what's not working and what kind of feedback your debugging has provided.

Comment: Well, if I use function to generate URL - my stuff does not work. If I copy generated URL into clipboard and hard code it into function- everything functions properly. I have been fighting it for the last 2 hours and can't figure out what's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the function was returning everything correctly, the parsing was not done right. I fixed it. JavaScript is hard for me to debug.